# What is the best way to handle large data with Tensorflow.js and tf.Tensor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow.js

## Question

I am using `tf.Tensor` and `tf.concat()` to handle large training data,
and I found continuous using of `tf.concat()` gets slow.
What is the best way to load large data from file to `tf.Tensor`?

## Background

I think it's common way to handle data by array in Javascript.
to achieve that, here is the rough steps to go.

### steps to load data from file to Array

1. read line from file
2. parse line to Javascript's Object
3. add that object to array by `Array.push()`
4. after finish reading line to end, we can use that array with for loop.

so I think I can use `tf.concat()` in similar way to above.

### steps to load data from file to tf.Tensor

1. read line from file
2. parse line to Javascript's Object
3. parse object to tf.Tensor
4. add tensor to original tensor by `tf.concat()`
5. after finish reading line to end, we can use that tf.Tensor

## Some code

Here is some code to measure both speed of `Array.push()` and `tf.concat()`

```
import * as tf from "@tensorflow/tfjs"

let t = tf.tensor1d([1])
let addT = tf.tensor1d([2])

console.time()
for (let idx = 0; idx < 50000; idx++) {
    if (idx % 1000 == 0) {
        console.timeEnd()
        console.time()
        console.log(idx)
    }
    t = tf.tidy(() => t.concat(addT))
}


let arr = []
let addA = 1
console.time()
for (let idx = 0; idx < 50000; idx++) {
    if (idx % 1000 == 0) {
        console.timeEnd()
        console.time()
        console.log(idx)
    }
    arr.push(addA)
}
```

## Measurement

We can see stable process on `Array.push()`,
but it gets slow on `tf.concat()`

### For tf.concat()

```
default: 0.150ms
0
default: 68.725ms
1000
default: 62.922ms
2000
default: 23.199ms
3000
default: 21.093ms
4000
default: 27.808ms
5000
default: 39.689ms
6000
default: 34.798ms
7000
default: 45.502ms
8000
default: 94.526ms
9000
default: 51.996ms
10000
default: 76.529ms
11000
default: 83.662ms
12000
default: 45.730ms
13000
default: 89.119ms
14000
default: 49.171ms
15000
default: 48.555ms
16000
default: 55.686ms
17000
default: 54.857ms
18000
default: 54.801ms
19000
default: 55.312ms
20000
default: 65.760ms
```

### For Array.push()

```
default: 0.009ms
0
default: 0.388ms
1000
default: 0.340ms
2000
default: 0.333ms
3000
default: 0.317ms
4000
default: 0.330ms
5000
default: 0.289ms
6000
default: 0.299ms
7000
default: 0.291ms
8000
default: 0.320ms
9000
default: 0.284ms
10000
default: 0.343ms
11000
default: 0.327ms
12000
default: 0.317ms
13000
default: 0.329ms
14000
default: 0.307ms
15000
default: 0.218ms
16000
default: 0.193ms
17000
default: 0.234ms
18000
default: 1.943ms
19000
default: 0.164ms
20000
default: 0.148ms
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though there is not a single way of creating a tensor, the answer of the questions lies to what is done with the tensors created.

#### Performance

tensors are immutable, therefore each time, `tf.concat` is called a new tensor is created.

```js
let x = tf.tensor1d([2]);
console.log(tf.memory()) // "numTensors": 1
const y = tf.tensor1d([3])
x = tf.concat([x, y])
console.log(tf.memory()) // "numTensors": 3,
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Load TensorFlow.js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.14.1"> </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

As we can see from the snippet above, the number of tensors that is created when tf.concat is called is **3** and not **2** . It is true that `tf.tidy` will dispose of unused tensors. But this operation of creating and disposing of tensors will become most and most costly as the created tensor is getting bigger and bigger. This is both an issue of memory consumption and computation since creating a new tensor will always delegate to a backend.

---

#### creating tensor from large data

Now that the issue of performance is understood, what is the best way to proceed ?

- create the whole array in js and when the whole array is completed, then create the tensor.

```js
for (i= 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  // fill array x
  x.push(dataValue)
}
// create the tensor
tf.tensor(x)
```

Though, it is the trivial solution, it is not always possible. Because create an array will keep data in memory and we can easily run out of memory with big data entries. Therefore sometimes, it might be best instead of creating the whole javascript array to create chunk of arrays and create a tensor from those chunk of arrays and start to process those tensors as soon as they are created. The chunk tensors can be merged using `tf.concat` again if necessary. But it might not always be required.

For instance we can call model.fit() repeatedly using chunk of tensors instead of calling it once with a big tensor that might take long to create. In this case, there is no need to concatenate the chunk tensors.

- if possible create a dataset using tf.data. This is the ideal solution, if we are next to fit a model with the data.

```js
function makeIterator() {

  const iterator = {
    next: () => {
      let result;
      if (index < data.length) {
        result = {value: dataValue, done: false};
        index++;
        return result;
      }
      return {value: dataValue, done: true};
    }
  };
  return iterator;
}
const ds = tf.data.generator(makeIterator);
```

The advantage of using tf.data is that the whole dataset is created by batches when needed during `model.fit` call.

Comment: Thank you for sharing multiple ways to handle.
Let me share what I met for my first try.
Originally I went with the way you suggested, "whole array in js, then create tensor".
With this way, I met out of memory error in Node.js and every time I had to add --max-old-space-size=4000 options to execute Node.

About tf.data, I am on waiting mode because tfjs team says it's in active development mode.

Maybe, I think I can go with the mix of Array.push() and tf.concat().
That means, create JavaScript Array with some portion of data, not 1line nor all lines, and tf.tensor() and tf.concat()

Comment: @edkeveked how would you implement loading the data asynchronously into the dataset, for example using the iterator?

Comment: Looking at the signature of `tf.data.generator`, it supports `Promise<iterator>`. So you can use it to load data asynchronously. If it is not clear, could you please create a new question and I will answer it ?

Answer (score 5):

While the `tf.concat` and `Array.push` function look and behave similar there is one big difference:

- `tf.concat` creates a **new tensor** from the input
- `Array.push` adds the input to the first array

### Examples

**`tf.concat`**

```js
const a = tf.tensor1d([1, 2]);
const b = tf.tensor1d([3]);
const c = tf.concat([a, b]);

a.print(); // Result: Tensor [1, 2]
b.print(); // Result: Tensor [3]
c.print(); // Result: Tensor [1, 2, 3]
```

The resulting variable `c` is a new Tensor while `a` and `b` are not changed.

**`Array.push`**

```js
const a = [1,2];
a.push(3);

console.log(a); // Result: [1,2,3]
```

Here, the variable `a` is directly changed.

### Impact on the runtime

For the runtime speed, this means that `tf.concat` copies all tensor values to a new tensor before adding the input. This obviously takes more time the bigger the array is that needs to be copied. In contrast to that, `Array.push` does not create a copy of the array and therefore the runtime will be more or less the same no matter how big the array is.

Note, that this is "by design" as tensors are immutable, so every operation on an existing tensor always creates a new tensor. Quote from the [docs](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/1.1.0/#Operations-Arithmetic):

> Tensors are immutable, so all operations always return new Tensors and never modify input Tensors.

Therefore, if you need to create a large tensor from input data it is advisable to first read all data from your file and merge it with "vanilla" JavaScript functions before creating a tensor from it.

### Handling data too big for memory

In case you have a dataset so big that you need to handle it in chunks because of memory restrictions, you have two options:

1. Use the [`trainOnBatch`](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/1.1.0/#tf.LayersModel.trainOnBatch) function
2. Use a dataset generator

#### Option 1: trainOnBatch

The [`trainOnBatch`](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/1.1.0/#tf.LayersModel.trainOnBatch) function allows to train on a batch of data instead of using the full dataset to it. Therefore, you can split your code into reasonable batches before training them, so you don't have to merge your data together all at once.

#### Option 2: Dataset generator

The other answer already went over the basics. This will allow you to use a [JavaScript generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) to prepare the data. I recommend to use the generator syntax instead of an iterator factory (used in the other answer) as it is the more modern JavaScript syntax.

**Exampe** (taken from the [docs](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/1.1.0/#data.generator)):

```js
function* dataGenerator() {
  const numElements = 10;
  let index = 0;
  while (index < numElements) {
    const x = index;
    index++;
    yield x;
  }
}

const ds = tf.data.generator(dataGenerator);
```

You can then use the [`fitDataset`](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/1.1.0/#tf.Sequential.fitDataset) function to train your model.

Comment: Thank you, Thomas, for sharing the official docs quote.

Also let me share my experience,
Actually for a first try, I coded with "vanilla" JavaScript but met out of memory issue,
so I started to find out better way to handle.

Comment: @ya9do I added two ways for that to do it to my answer. You can use [`trainOnBatch`](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/1.1.0/#tf.LayersModel.trainOnBatch) or a [DataSet](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/1.1.0/#class:data.Dataset). More details in the answer :)

Comment: @ThomasDondorf do you know if you can also use async generators? i failed to use them so far