# How to transform data in angular to correct tensor format?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, tensorflow.js

I'm working on a machine learning project and I'm trying to deploy my algorithm with angular.
I have already uploaded the pretrained model correctly and I managed to upload data from a csv, but now I have problems to properly transform the data I have to the correct format of tensors.
My model is a LSTM Neural Network that expects timewindows with the length of 60 of accelerometer data (x-axis, y-axis and z-axis) to predict human activities so tensors of the format [any, 60,3]
Down below you can find the important part of my code that I have up to now

Loading the model here

```
async loadModel() {
   this.model = await tf.loadLayersModel('assets/tfjs_model/model.json');
 };
```

Right now I have a placeholder with the tf.ones() function to simply test, if my prediction works (it does work!!)

```
 async predictProcess() {
   const output = this.model.predict([tf.ones([10, 60, 3])]) as any;    
   this.predictions = Array.from(output.dataSync());
   console.log(this.predictions);
```

};

This is the part of the code, where I load the data

```
getDataRecordsArrayFromCSVFile(csvRecordsArray: any, headerLength: any) {
let dataArr = [];

for (let i = 0; i < csvRecordsArray.length; i++) {
  let data = (<string>csvRecordsArray[i]).split(',');

  // FOR EACH ROW IN CSV FILE IF THE NUMBER OF COLUMNS
  // ARE SAME AS NUMBER OF HEADER COLUMNS THEN PARSE THE DATA
  if (data.length == headerLength) {

    let csvRecord: CSVRecord = new CSVRecord();

  //  csvRecord.timestep = Number(data[0].trim());
    csvRecord.xAxis = Number(data[1].trim());
    csvRecord.yAxis = Number(data[2].trim());
    csvRecord.zAxis = Number(data[3].trim());

    dataArr.push(csvRecord);
  }
}
return dataArr;
}
```

This is the CSVRecord class

```
export class CSVRecord {
  public timestep: any;
  public xAxis: any;
  public yAxis: any;
  public zAxis: any;
}
```

Comment: I acknowedge the answers and the time people took to answer my questions and I'm trying to work things out myself. But while doing that, new questions/problems come up. I'm simply seeking for help here, because I'm new to certain parts of programming...

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating an object to populate `dataArr`, it will be better to use an array

```
if (data.length == headerLength) {

    let csvRecord: number[] = [];

  //  csvRecord.timestep = Number(data[0].trim());
    csvRecord.push(Number(data[1].trim()));
    csvRecord.push(Number(data[2].trim()));
    csvRecord.push(Number(data[3].trim()));

    dataArr.push(csvRecord);
  }
```

Then to create a tensor out of `dataArr`, you can use

```
tf.tensor(dataArr)
```

Using `tf.tensor`, it will create a tensor of shape `[dataArr.length, 3]`

But if `dataArr` is a big array, trying to create a tensor of it directly will cause memory issue as the whole data will be uploaded directly to the tensor backend when it starts to be used during computation. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55929960/what-is-the-best-way-to-handle-large-data-with-tensorflow-js-and-tf-tensor/55940423#55940423) discusses how to handle large data when creating a tensor.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot - also the link on how to deal with large datasets! :)
Do you have an idea, how I can transform that tensor of this shape into a tensor of the shape [any,60,3]? So my algorithms expects batches of 60 data points with x-axis, y-axis, z-axis data. And any depending on the overall dataset (e.g. if I have 36o datapoints, the shape would be [6,60,3]

Comment: you can use `tensor.reshape([-1, 60, 3])`. However, for the reshape to work, you need to have a number of data multiple of `60 * 3 = 180`