# is there a way to make tensorflow js read/train data from a json file instead of a csv?

Tags: javascript, json, machine-learning, training-data, tensorflow.js

So I'm new with machine learning and have been struggling with making my model train from the data provided from a json file. I have no problem training with a csv. Also converting the json to csv is not an option since the json file is not simple.

Comment: You can write scripts to convert the JSON file to CSV format so what do you mean it is not `simple`?

Comment: Then that is an issue with how you convert the JSON to CSV try using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871524/how-can-i-convert-json-to-csv) and seeing if it works.

Comment: I did try to convert the json file to csv but it does not work for me because the json file has some parameters that have arrays that also have arays.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, tensorflow.js does not offer a way to load json data for training. So the options there are

- Use a json to csv converter

That way `tf.data.csv` can be used to read the file

- Use a custom loader

First one needs to get the data using the fetch API for instance. Then, the dataset needs to be constructed with the data returned. When the data is large, everythings needs not to be loaded in memory at the same time. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55929960/what-is-the-best-way-to-handle-large-data-with-tensorflow-js-and-tf-tensor) discusses how to handle that case.

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid doing the conversion on your own; use the Javascript JSON library for functions like `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` that go recursively deep in an array and turn it into a Javascript-subscriptable object.

Answer (score -1):

Use this code convert json to csv.

```
import os
import json
import pandas as pd

def labelme_json_to_csv(json_folder, output_csv):
    csv_data = []
    for json_file in os.listdir(json_folder):
        if json_file.endswith(".json"):
            with open(os.path.join(json_folder, json_file)) as f:
                data = json.load(f)

                # Extracting image filename (assuming 'imagePath' is present in the LabelMe JSON)
                img_filename = data['imagePath']

                # Extracting image width and height
                img_width = data['imageWidth']
                img_height = data['imageHeight']

                for shape in data['shapes']:
                    label = shape['label']
                    points = shape['points']

                    # Extracting bounding box coordinates
                    xmin = min(points, key=lambda x: x[0])[0]
                    ymin = min(points, key=lambda x: x[1])[1]
                    xmax = max(points, key=lambda x: x[0])[0]
                    ymax = max(points, key=lambda x: x[1])[1]

                    # Appending data to CSV format
                    csv_data.append([img_filename, label, img_width, img_height, xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax])

    # Creating a DataFrame
    column_names = ['filename', 'class', 'width', 'height', 'xmin', 'ymin', 'xmax', 'ymax']
    df = pd.DataFrame(csv_data, columns=column_names)

    # Save the DataFrame to a CSV file
    df.to_csv(output_csv, index=False)
    print(f"Conversion completed. CSV file saved as '{output_csv}'.")

def main():
    train_json_folder = "images/train"
    test_json_folder = "images/test"
    
    labelme_json_to_csv(train_json_folder, "train_labels.csv")
    labelme_json_to_csv(test_json_folder, "test_labels.csv")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```