# Showing the Val Acc in tensorflow.js

Tags: json, validation, machine-learning, metrics, tensorflow.js

So I'm new to tensorflow.js and I have been trying to practice with an exercise.
I have a json dataset and I want to show the val acc but all the example that I could find had .csv data sets. I would appreciate it if anyone could send me a link to such an example so I can better understand or to explain it here in the answers.
Here is what I'm doing:

```
 const trainingData = tf.tensor1d(horses.map(item => 
findAvg( filterOdds(item.prices))
))
const testingData = tf.tensor1d(horsesTesting.map(item =>
   findAvg( filterOdds(item.prices))
      ));
const outputData = tf.tensor2d(horses.map(item => [
        
        item.position === 1 ? 1 : 0,
        item.position !== 1 ? 1 : 0,

        // item.position != 1 ? 1 : 0,
      ]))

 model.fit(trainingData, outputData, {epochs: 10})
  .then((history) => {
    // console.log(history)
    model.predict(testingData).print()

      })
```

Output: 4404ms 184us/step - acc=0.890 loss=0.0866 precision=0.00

what I found in the examples:

```
const trainingUrl1 = 'wdbc-train.csv';
            
            // Take a look at the 'wdbc-train.csv' file and specify the column
            // that should be treated as the label in the space below.
            // HINT: Remember that you are trying to build a classifier that 
            // can predict from the data whether the diagnosis is malignant or benign.
            const trainingData = tf.data.csv(trainingUrl1, {
                
                columnConfigs: {
                    diagnosis: {
                        isLabel: true
                    }
                }
                
            });
 const convertedTrainingData = // YOUR CODE HERE
             trainingData.map(({xs, ys}) => {

                      return{ xs: Object.values(xs), ys: Object.values(ys)};
                  }).batch(10);
            
            const testingUrl2 = 'wdbc-test.csv';

const testingData = tf.data.csv(testingUrl2, {
                
                 columnConfigs: {
                    diagnosis: {
                        isLabel: true
                    }
                }
                
            });
const convertedTestingData = // YOUR CODE HERE
                  
testingData.map(({xs, ys}) => {
return{ xs: Object.values(xs), ys: Object.values(ys)};
                  }).batch(10);
await model.fitDataset(convertedTrainingData, 
                             {epochs:35,
                              validationData: convertedTestingData,
                              callbacks:{
                                  onEpochEnd: async(epoch, logs) =>{
                                      console.info("Epoch: " + epoch + " Loss: " + logs.loss + " Accuracy: " + logs.acc + "  val_acc "  + logs.val_acc);
                                  }
                              }});
```

Output:

```
Epoch: 1 Loss: 0.08664028346538544 Accuracy: 0.784  val_acc 0.919
```

Comment: I am not sure I understood the question. You are already displaying the accuracy, aren't you ?

Comment: I noticed that there's a difference between accuracy and validation accuracy. What is the difference between them and how can I display validation accuracy in my code when using json data instead of .csv?

Comment: The code for displaying accuracy would be the same, regardless of the dataset format.
The accuracy is printed in `callbacks::onEpochEnd` -- there you have console.info / console.log.

To see all the fields in `logs`, you can use `console.dir(logs)`

Answer (score 0):

There are two options for loading the dataset already discussed in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65316105/is-there-a-way-to-make-tensorflow-js-read-train-data-from-a-json-file-instead-of):

- convert json to csv and then use the csvDataSet loader
- create a custom loader using json. The csvDataSet loader [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/blob/07ce4516134fff8283ec43c4497c91a0f6a28dda/tfjs-data/src/datasets/csv_dataset.ts#L46) can help started

Regarding `acc` and `val_acc`, the first is for the training data and the second for the testing data